# issue with fitting data with TensorFlow Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am attempting to create a model for deciphering hand written text. The issue I am encountering right now is feeding my data to the model.

I start out with a list of file names with each file as a picture. I also have a list of labels for each.

I then iterate through the file names and load those images.

```
for i in range(len(images)):
    print(len(images) - i)
    images[i] = np.array(cv2.imread(images[i]))
```

I then compile the model. And feed the lists to it as such.

```
self.model.fit(np.array(imgs), np.array(labels), epochs=10, validation_data=(np.array(test_images), np.array(test_labels)), callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (80, 1)
```

My np array of images is size (80, 1), which is what I thought I was supposed to be feeding to the model, but I am confused as to why it is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Conv2D expects input:

> Input shape: 4D tensor with shape: (batch_size, channels, rows, cols)
>   if data_format='channels_first' or 4D tensor with shape: (batch_size,
>   rows, cols, channels) if data_format='channels_last'.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D

Answer (score 0):

What you should be feeding the model should have the shape `(batch_size, h, w, c)`
where `h, w, c` are height, width and number of channels in the image respectively.
The problem could be that cv2 cannot find the images in which case it will not through an error it will simply return none resulting in the shape that you got here `(80, 1)`. You could add a check in the for loop for none values as a start and try to get the right path for your images